# Problems using Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I've been using Spring JDBC with great success but I am having alot of trouble with this project. I'll post the code links here(it's just a small and silly project to test if I can get it up and running so that I can use Hibernate in the future):

xml-file: http://codepaste.net/uw19zc

main-file: http://codepaste.net/iks1cp

I get tons of errors such as

```
[Fatal Error] bean2.out.xml:1:1: Premature end of file.
13:21:39,471 FATAL [main] Main  - getAssociatedStylesheets failed
```

and I haven't created a.out.xml file.

Comment: post the xml and error that you are getting in your question please

Answer (score 45, accepted):

This error is due to incorrect parsing of the xml file. 
Using Eclipse to validate it gives the error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'beans' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.

There appears to be some strange character in between one or many of those `<bean>` declarations. Have you copied this text from somewhere else?

Remove all spaces and newline characters between `<bean>` definitions and put them back with your editor.

**UPDATE**
Copying & pasting into notepad++ the text in the codepaste you provided, and setting the charset to UTF-8 showed these characters in the blank lines: <kbd>xA0</kbd>. This is the standard Unicode translation for `&nbsp;`. This is likely to be the cause of this problem.

This validates ok for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
     <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HibernateDB" />
        <property name="username" value="HibernateDB" />
        <property name="password" value="java" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configurationClass" value="org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>hdao.HibernateObject</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean><bean id="springHibernateOperator" class="hdao.SpringHibernateOperatorImplementation">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Great answer! Although now something strange happened. When my main method tries to instatiate ClassPathXmlApplicationContext i get exceptions:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [bean2.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Cacheable

I do not understand why, haven't i written the xml-file correctly?

Comment: The same error is discussed [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/509836/ORM/java/Hibernate-java-lang-ClassNotFoundException-javax). Make sure you've got the [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api/1.0.0.Final) jar in your classpath/maven dependencies. This class is also present in the [Java EE 6 api jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/javaee-api/6.0/javaee-api-6.0.jar). Also, you might want to accept this answer and post another question regarding this matter.

Comment: You are correct, I solved it but I will accept the answer, thanks =)

Comment: Same problem, opening your file in a good XML editor will quickly point out where your bad character is

Answer (score 7):

If you are in linux, use `cat -v file-name.xml` to detect special "invisible" characters like 'M-BM-' in your xml file

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes there are hidden characters in dependencies or some bean definitions, which you copy from some tutorial's website. best way to find out those hidden characters do a `

> ctrl + shift + F

this will format your document and you can see that hidden character in between some tag 
`