# persistence.xml not working

Tags: jpa, persistence.xml

I have a problem with running a web project with JPA. Netbeans shows the message:

> The module has not been deployed.
>   See the server log for details.

I'm using Glassfish as a server, it shows following error message:

> Grave: Exception lors du déploiement de l'application [delegation_anomalie] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 122; Fichier de descripteur de déploiement META-INF/persistence.xml dans l'archive [classes].  cvc-complex-type.2.1 : L'élément 'property' ne doit comporter aucun enfant ([children]) de type caractère ou élément d'information, car le type de contenu du type est vide.

Which means that element `proprety` should have no children.

Here is my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="delegation_anomaliePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <class>dbclass.web.Profile</class>
    <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/delegation_anomalie"> </property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"></property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sde"> </property>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"> </property>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please translate the exception message into English and this is not a JSF problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this page help: [Problems using Spring Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835389/problems-using-spring-hibernate)

The above link suggests you to remove all line breaks between tags and try again. It is possible that there are some invisible special characters between your  tags and causing this issue.

Comment: I had the same problem, and that was the issue indeed. Thank you.